# He can't find any as good tenant as her

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatically correct way to say that?

> He cant find any as good tenant as her
>
> He cant find as any good tenant as her
>
> He cant find any tenant as good as her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your first two options is grammatical. Your third is perfectly acceptable except among very fastidious users of English.  (As pointed out in a kindly comment, the original question was edited while I was originally answering. Originally, only the first two options in the current question were proposed. I have now edited this answer to address the edited question.)

Colloquial English.

He can't find a tenant as good as her.

He can't find any tenant as good as her.

Fussy English.

He can't find {a/any} tenant as good as she.

Colloquial and Fussy.

He can't find {a/any} tenant as good as she was.

He can't find {a/any} tenant as good as she would have been.

The latter two are different in meaning, but both are grammatical.

Comment: I'd suggest **He can't find another tenant as good as she was.**

Comment: You might have to edit this answer.  You begin with "Neither is idiomatic", and yet the OP lists three options.  I think this is because the OP edited their question shortly before you answered.

Comment: @MaxW That works too IF she ever was a tenant. This exposes a weakness in the original question: it is not clear whether it is comparing past fact with current fact or comparing current fact with conceivable but contra-factual alternative. Another problem is that the question has been edited severely. Originally it asked only which of "any as good tenant as her" or "as any good tenant as her" was correct. Neither is as I stated in my answer.